# Next.js PWA (Service Worker + Manifest.json)

Tags: manifest, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, next.js, lighthouse

I am using Next.js to develop a Server Side Rendering website and I want to make it a Progressive Web App but the problem I couldn't find the way to make it happen correctly.

When I build the application it serves correctly the service worker but there is no manifest.json and in some projects examples it serves the manifest.json but I tried it in Lighthouse audit and it says

> Service worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url

One of the examples I used
[Create Next App With Service Worker Precache](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-sw-precache)

I think that the problem is that the start_url is . or / and not a valid file because in Next.js there is no index.html to serve from the start.

In summary
I am looking for an example using Next.js to build it to a dist folder and when I serve it it has a valid Service Worker and a valid Web Manifest.

Comment: Have a look at `/public` directory in your next.js project. There are files that are served statically and it is 'root' url for such files like `manifest.json` etc.

Answer (score 16):

### A. Some file are expected to be found at "/"

You have this error because browsers expect some files to be served from the root of the server, including:

1. `/manifest.json`
2. `/sitemap.xml`
3. `/favicon.ico`
4. `/robots.txt`
5. `/browserconfig.xml`
6. `/site.webmanifest`

While the majority of these paths can be set with meta tags, older browsers just ignore them and error if these exact file names are not served.

### B. Configure alternative paths and use NextJS static file

At the time of writing, there is [ongoing work for supporting offline](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/861) in NextJS. But it's not ready yet.

If you don't need to support older browsers and you don't want advanced SEO, you can use NextJS's `Head` component ([see documentation](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22shortcut%20icon%22%20href=%22/static/icons/favicon.ico?v=bOML8dwReQ%22)) to define the `manifest.json` path like you would for any NextJS static file:

```
import Head from "next/head"

export default () => (
    <Head>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/static/site.webmanifest" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico"
    </Head>
)
```

Please note that `robots.txt` cannot be serve from a subdirectory ([source](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/89409)), so this solution is not a good fit if you need to define this file.

### C. Serve these files like expected

The proper solution would be to serve these files from your express server like so

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
const { join } = require('path')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const rootStaticFiles = [
        '/manifest.json',
        '/sitemap.xml',
        '/favicon.ico',
        '/robots.txt',
        '/browserconfig.xml',
        '/site.webmanifest',
      ]
      if (rootStaticFiles.indexOf(parsedUrl.pathname) > -1) {
        const path = join(__dirname, 'static', parsedUrl.pathname)
        app.serveStatic(req, res, path)
      } else {
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    })
      .listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
      })
  })
```

**Note**: This code directly comes from [the NextJS examples repository](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/root-static-files/server.js)

Answer (score 2):

here are the steps to make your next.js progressive. [check the example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/progressive-web-app)

- `npm i next-pwa`
- next.config.json

```
    const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
    module.exports = withPWA({
      pwa: {
        dest: "public",
        
      },
      ...
    });
```

- add manifest.json and icons to public folder from the example. However, icons directory is missing "maskable_icon.png". So create a maskable icon [from here](https://maskable.app/editor) then add this to "manifest.json".

  ```
   {
      "src": "path/to/maskable_icon.png",
      "sizes": "196x196",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
  ```
- add those tags to `import Head from "next/head"`. `Head` is used for better SEO setting. [check the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head)*

  ```
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="Description" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords" />
    <title>Next.js PWA Example</title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <link
      href="/icons/favicon-16x16.png"
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="16x16"
    />
    <link
      href="/icons/favicon-32x32.png"
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-icon.png"></link>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#317EFB" />
  </Head>
  ```
- lastly check if it is working. add Lighhouse extension to chrome dev tools from chrome app store and run start the performance.